# Anonymous users skip comment approval but they shouldn't

Tags: users, comments

In my drupal 8.6.1 news blog anonymous users can skip comment approval althouth permissions are set to not skip. I rebuilt the permissions but nothing changed.

Also in comments page I see that some anonymous users are linked to an anonymous user account with id = 0 !

My site is not hacked and I can't understand what is going on.

Check this image!

[image]

Is there a chance that my drupal 8.6.1 has this unexpected behavior because is running on server with php 5.6?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you see their comments when you're not logged into drupal? Are you sure you're not using an admin account that can see everything?

Comment: Yes I can see the comments when I am not logged in. Yes I am sure, I use user with id  = 1.

Comment: By default, the anonymous user account is only the one shown as _Anonymous (not verified)_. You can change the anonymous user name in /admin/config/people/accounts to, for example, ΑΝΟΝΥΜΟUΣ, but you cannot have two anonymous users with different names.

Comment: The ΑΝΩΝΥΜΟΥΣ not verified is the greek version that's why I didn't consider as wrong. But why there is a link for /user/0 for whom I have to permission to see? There is no user id =0 in my site / db.

Comment: I have the same problem... running on php 7.1. Did you solve this issue? Did you add a bug in the issue queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my side, the problem was the use of the [cleantalk](https://www.drupal.org/project/cleantalk) module.

In this module, in the configuration page: `admin/config/content/cleantalk/settings`

You must uncheck **"Enable automoderation"** if you do not want to override the "Skip comment approval" permission

Comment: Thank you very much! Cleantalk caused the error! Couldn't find it after so much search.